# When do I need to install python-rosinstall?

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ROS fuerte before.

Now I want to use ROS groovy on the same laptop.

I found that I can run rosinstall command now, but I also can install python-rosinstall.

What's their difference?

When is the case to install python-rosinstall?

I run rosinstall:

```
  sam@sam:~$ rosinstall 
  
  usage: rosinstall [OPTIONS] INSTALL_PATH [ROSINSTALL FILES OR DIRECTORIES]
  see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall
  
  Common Option:
  -n or --nobuild (don't perform a 'make core_cools' on the ros stack)
  
  Type 'rosinstall --help' for usage.
  
  Common invocations:
  
  initial checkout:   rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=ros-full&overlay=no"
  subsequent update:  rosinstall ~/ros
  
  
  sam@sam:~$
```

I run sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall

```
  sam@sam:~$ LANG=C
  sam@sam:~$ sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    libgsl0-dev omniorb-nameserver libomnithread3-dev omniidl omniorb libomnithread3c2 libavahi-core-dev libomniorb4-1 libgsl0ldbl
    libomniorb4-dev
  Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
  The following extra packages will be installed:
    bzr python-bzrlib python-vcstools
  Suggested packages:
    bzr-doc bzr-gtk bzr-svn python-bzrlib.tests bzrtools python-kerberos python-gpgme python-bzrlib-dbg
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    bzr python-bzrlib python-rosinstall python-vcstools
  0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  Need to get 1,877 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 9,119 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63651/when-do-i-need-to-install-python-rosinstall?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install rosinstall using pip in the past? If so, you want to remove it, and move to the version found in python-rosinstall.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-05-27**:
Yes,I use pip to install rosinstall. Is python-rosinstall the newer version of rosinstall? What's their difference? Thank you~

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-05-27**:
The pip installer was an approach tried, and then abandoned. Newer versions of rosinstall have not been distributed via pip for quite some time. If the old version isn't acting up, you're probably fine to continue using it, but if you use rosws or wstool (the catkin replacement), these depend on ...

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-05-27**:
python-rosinstall. And MOST IMPORTANTLY, do not install python-rosinstall without first removing the pip version -- or you'll end up with all sorts of impossible to debug errors because the new stuff is still finding parts of the old stuff...

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-05-27**:
Thank you for so detail explanation. So how to remove the old rosinstall?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-29**:
See: http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153